# INSERT не срабатывает после SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Не могу понять свою ошибку (PHP 7.3)

```
$db = new test_mysqli();
$dbSelect = "SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name = '".$_POST['name']."';";
$resultSelect = $db->query($dbSelect);
echo "Row:".$resultSelect->num_rows."!<br>";
if ($resultSelect->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Fail. Name ".$_POST['name']." already used <br>";
    while ($row = $resultSelect->fetch_assoc()) 
        echo $row['name']." ".$row['password']."<br>";
} else {
    $dbInsert = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['password']."', '".gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s')."');";
    echo $dbInsert."<br>";
    $resultInser = $db->query($dbInsert);
    if ($resultInser)
        echo "Success. ".$resultInser->insert_id."!<br>";
    else
        echo "Fail. ".$db->error."<br>";
    $resultInser->close();
}
$resultSelect->close();
$db->close();
```

Результат

```
Row:1!
Fail. Name qwe3 already used
qwe3 3ewq
```

Select работает

```
Row:0!
INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, 'qwe4', '4ewq', '2020-03-09 11:43:17');
Success. !
```

Insert не работает. В базе ничего не появляется. Корректность запроса проверял вписывая в базу 2ую строчку мануально. `$db->error` тоже пуст.

Но если проверку `SELECT` вырезать, `INSERT` создаст запись в базе, хотя и не вернув `insert_id`.

Comment: А просто вставить строку через PHPMyAdmin  в эту таблицу пробовали? Работает? Ещё, в порядке глупой идеи, проверьте, нет ли каких-то триггеров в таблице, которые бы мешали в неё добавлять новые записи.

Comment: @Quazimorda `Корректность запроса проверял вписывая в базу 2ую строчку мануально`.

Comment: действительно, невнимательно прочитал ваше сообщение. Есть мнение, опять же в порядке бреда, что пока открыт один запрос $resultSelect = $db->query($dbSelect); вы не можете создать новый $resultInser = $db->query($dbInsert); Попробуйте перед инсёртом закрыть предыдущий запрос с селектом.

Comment: Как предположение, `query` у `mysqli` возвращает объект `mysqli_query`, чекни, что лежит в `$resultSelect->num_rows`, мб в этом беда, именно это условие у вас не выполняется. Задамьпь `$resultSelect->num_rows > 0` и будет понятно, там ли трабла, если нет, то чекай `$resultSelect->num_rows`, далее сам `$resultSelect`, ну и `$db`, коль на то пошло, с этими данными будет абсолютно все понятно, скидывай.

Comment: @Quazimorda нет, с закрытым `$resultSelect` тоже самое, но дело всё-же в этом. Убрав весь код проверки с селектом, инсерт, хотя и не выдав `inser_id` сработал, запись в базе появилась. Спасибо, хоть-бы понял, где собака зарыта.

Comment: @Borislav чекни `сдв`, это лечится. Самому в лом читать всё, когда народ строчит абзацы текста и выкладывает пару файлов с 50+ сток кода, но мой пост довольно краткий.

Comment: Скажу очередную глупость, но может вам явно открывать новую транзакцию для вставки данных? Чтобы проверка оставалась в другой транзакции, а в этой не было ничего, кроме insert into...?

Comment: @Quazimorda я не из этих =D Глупости, извраты и трешкод конечно наше всё, но когда только учишься и не торопишься хочется разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально вопрос был сформулирован как "INSERT выполняется без ошибок, но в БД ничего нет", поэтому ниже идет ответ на него. Вопрос же "INSERT не срабатывает после SELECT" гораздо более примитивный, и полностью покрывается третьим пунктом.

---

Причин для такого поведения может быть две

1. Где-то выше по коду стартует транзакция/отключается автокоммит. Для решения проблемы надо вернуть БД в нормальный режим атомарных запросов.
2. Проверка вставки производится не в той базе данных, к которой подключается пхп скрипт. Для проверки сделать запрос на получение только что добавленной строки в том же пхп скрипте.
3. Ошибка всё-таки **есть**. Для проверки надо сконфигурировать пхп и mysqli, чтобы они показывали сообщения об ошибках.

   - [Отображение ошибок PHP](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)
   - [Отображение ошибок mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting)

Answer (score -1):

Заменил две переменные `$resultSelect` и `$resultInser` на одну `$queryResult` и заработало. Я ваш `php` шатал с матом-перематом.

```
$db = new mpo_mysqli();
$dbSelect = "SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE name = '".$_POST['name']."';";
$queryResult = $db->query($dbSelect);
echo "Row:".$queryResult->num_rows."!<br>";
while ($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()) 
        echo $row['name']." ".$row['password']."<br>";
$fail = $queryResult->num_rows > 0;
$queryResult->close();
if ($fail) {
    echo "Fail. Name ".$_POST['name']." already used <br>";
} else {
    $dbInsert = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['password']."', '".gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s')."');";
    echo $dbInsert."<br>";
    $queryResult = $db->query($dbInsert);
    if ($queryResult)
        echo "Success. ".$queryResult->insert_id."!<br>";
    else
        echo "Fail. ".$db->error."<br>";
    $queryResult->close();
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: Дада, конечно, это пхп виноват, что код из одних ошибок состоит :)

Comment: @Ипатьев а где я мог вообще узнать, что в череде запросов нужно использовать одну и ту-же переменную, как бы странно это не было. И то, что эти ошибки приходится находить на кофейной гуще.

Comment: И `error_reporting` и `mysqli_report` молчали как партизаны.

Comment: Дада, проблема *конечно же* в имени переменной, какие сомнения :) А с ошибками всё просто. Программисты читают сообщение об ошибке и исправляют её, а остальным - да, приходится на кофейной гуще, методом тыка, авось в результате хаотичных телодвижений случайно само заработает.

Comment: если что, у тебя до сих пор в коде как минимум одна ошибка, про которую пхп тебе оборался

Comment: Я с этого и ору, что ошибок не вижу. Куда php орёт? В консоли браузера пусто...

Comment: а при чем здесь консоль **javascript**, я извиняюсь?

Comment: @Ипатьев ты на полном серьёзе уверен, что начинающий сходу знает, как устроен лог ошибок на `php`... это ведь настолько не уникально.